# Concurrently incrementing counter in file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http, concurrency

I have a file with an integer, say 10.

Each http request my nodejs app reads the integer from the file, adds 1 and writes back the result:

```
fs.readFile(..., result => ...fs.writeFile(..., result + 1) );
```

If two http requests arrive almost simultaneously, is it possible that both read `10` and write `11`, or will the file always end up containing `12`?

If not the latter, how is this supposed to be resolved such that it always is?

Comment: one possible solution is readFileSync/writeFileSync ... or perhaps some locking mechanism of your own desing

Comment: Could you store the integer in a cache which is incremented at each request, and periodically written to the file?

Comment: @JaromandaX doesn't opening a file in 'rw' mode already serialize access to it?

Answer (score 0):

i think it should help you.
We just checking our variable 'proceeding' and if task already running we wait before it finish

```js
const incrementor = {
  proceeding : false,
  result : 0,
  doWork: async function(){
      //waiting
      while(proceeding){
      //dont know should i use it in backend
        await new Promise(resolve=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve();
          },5)
        })
      }
      proceeding = true;
      result = await fs.readFile('dwadwad.dwad');  
      result++;
      fs.writeFileSync(..., result);
      proceeding = false;
  }
}
```